# Why doesnt the gravitional force exert a moment around the $z$-axis?

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, torque, constrained-dynamics

I just solved the problem below, but I have some questions regarding my solution.

[image]

In my solution, I assumed that the total angular momentum around the $z$-axis was conserved. Which was shown to be the correct assumption since I got the right answer. In order for the angular momentum to be conserved, we have to show that the torque exerted by the forces along the $z$-axis is 0. Of course, the normal force goes along the direction of the radius, so there can be no torque generated. But the gravitational force is always perpendicular to the radius from the $z$-axis, so how come it doesnt generate a torque around it?

Comment: "*But the gravitational force is always perpendicular to the radius from the z axis, so how come it doesnt generate a torque around it?*" What do you mean by this? You're not confusing a vector for force with a vector for torque are you? "*we have to show that the torque exerted by the forces along the z axis is 0*" Forces are exerted *along* a vector. Torques are exerted *about* or *around* a vector via right hand convention. That's the difference I referred to earlier.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear. Thank you for correcting me. Since torque is calculated as the cross product between the moment arm (our radius) and the force ( gravitional force). However, these vectors (radial vector and force vector) are perpendicular to one another so the gravitational force has to exert a torque about the z - axis. Meaning I can't assume that the angular momentum is conserved.

Comment: It does seem like some kind of angular acceleration should result like how a ball speeds up going down a straight ramp, but in this case the ramp is circular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading your sketch correctly, the force vector of gravity points along the $z$-axis, and the torque is the cross product of the position vector and the force vector. The cross product of two vectors is perpendicular to both vectors, so the torque caused by gravity is normal to the $z$ axis and cannot have a component along it.

Comment: In that case, we can't say that the angular momentum is conserved along the direction given by the vector formed by the cross product of the position and force vector. Is that true?

Comment: That's correct. However, that vector is constantly changing as the particle is circling around the $z$-axis. So only angular momentum around $z$ is conserved.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The gravitation force cause a torque about the y axis , so you are right the torque about the z or x axis is zero

Comment: Thank you Eli :))